# usleep not working, invalid argument error

Tags: c, usleep

usleep just isn't waiting any time, the errno variable accuses an invalid argument is being passed on to the function, even if i use the useconds_t type I just get the same error over and over.

I have no idea what's going on here, here's the file I made for some testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int delay=500000;
    int err=errno;
    printf("%d\n", err);
    usleep(delay);
    err = errno;
    printf("%d\n", err);
    return 0;
}
```

strace output:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7fffec458c30 /* 22 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffff9f5d4f0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1757000
brk(0x17581c0)                          = 0x17581c0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x1757880)      = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="DESKTOP-PRJN4N7", ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/mnt/c/Users/User/dmsh/gm/a.out", 4096) = 31
brk(0x17791c0)                          = 0x17791c0
brk(0x177a000)                          = 0x177a000
mprotect(0x4bd000, 12288, PROT_READ)    = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x4, 0x1), ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(1, "0\n", 20
)                      = 2
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=500000000}, NULL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(1, "22\n", 322
)                     = 3
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: It delays half a second for me. You should only check `errno` if `usleep` returns `-1`.

Comment: For me it's actually returning -1, for any value of usec passed. And errno is always 22

Comment: With a tiny handful of exceptions, all C library functions are allowed to set errno to a nonzero value *even if they succeed*. usleep might have done this, and printf might have also. Check what usleep returns, and also measure the time actually slept (e.g. by calling gettimeofday before and after).

Comment: If usleep really is returning -1 for any input, something is very wrong. Please recompile your program using `cc -static`, and then post the *complete and unedited* output of `strace ./a.out`. (Linking statically is just to eliminate a bunch of irrelevant chatter from the beginning of the strace log. If what you get is "strace: command not found", install that utility and try again.)

Comment: Done, how should I post the output? I'm new here sorry

Comment: Printing a human-readable error message instead of just a raw `errno` value makes it easier - use `perror()` or `strerror()` for that.

Comment: @t-taketsune Please edit the strace output into your question. Look for the tiny gray word "edit" at the bottom of the question, under the tags. That's a button. Yes, it's bad UI design. Sorry.

Comment: You should probably also update your code to show that you are checking `usleep()`'s return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/mnt/c/Users/User/dmsh/gm/a.out", 4096) = 31

The path in that line suggests you're using WSL to run your program in Windows, not a straight up Linux or Unix system.

> clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=500000000}, NULL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)

And that one tells us you're using a glibc version in WSL that implements `usleep()` in terms of `clock_nanosleep()` (My Ubuntu 16.04 WSL installation uses `nanosleep()`, fwiw. Apparently the glibc people changed the `usleep()` implementation at some point.)

The WSL linux emulation layer doesn't support `clock_nanosleep()` with a `CLOCK_REALTIME` timer. To verify, this demo program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  struct timespec timeout = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 500000000 };
  int err;
  if ((err = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, &timeout, NULL)) != 0) {    
    printf("clock_nanosleep realtime failed: %s\n", strerror(err));
  } else {
    puts("clock_nanosleep realtime worked.");
  }      
  if ((err = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &timeout, NULL)) != 0) {
    printf("clock_nanosleep monotonic failed: %s\n", strerror(err));
  } else {
    puts("clock_nanosleep monotonic worked.");
  }
  if (nanosleep(&timeout, NULL) < 0) {
    perror("nanosleep");
  } else {
    puts("nanosleep worked.");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

should print out

```
clock_nanosleep realtime failed: Invalid argument
clock_nanosleep monotonic worked.
nanosleep worked.
```

when you compile and run it.

The fix is to just not use `usleep()` (Which is deprecated anyways and no longer in POSIX). Try `nanosleep()` or the above `clock_nanosleep()` with a monotonic timer.