# Fortran call to sleep does not block program

Tags: fortran, gfortran, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the most basic Fortran program:

```
program sleep
    print*, "Sleeping"
    call sleep(30)
    print*, "Done"
end program sleep
```

which I compile with `gfortran sleep.f90` (version 9.3.0). From what I understood from the [`sleep`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gfortran/SLEEP.html) documentation, this program is supposed to sleep for 30 seconds, i.e. I should expect to see "Done" being printed 30 seconds after "Sleeping". This doesn't happen: I see both print statements appearing instantaneously, suggesting that `call sleep(30)` does not block my program in any way. Doing `call sleep(10000)` didn't make any difference. I am compiling and running this program on a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: What operating system do you use? Try `30000` or even `30000000`, what happens?

Comment: Related...? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230252/sleep-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04-wsl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930112/why-doesnt-php-sleep-work-in-the-windows-subsystem-linux

Comment: @roygvib This problem seems related to the first issue you linked (about sleep on WSL). I've replaced `/usr/bin/sleep` with a [Python solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253473/777167), but unfortunately this doesn't propagate into my code. Does Fortran use `/usr/bin/sleep` internally? Could I overload the call to `sleep` in Fortran somehow?

Comment: I think Fortran do *not* use `/usr/bin/sleep` but rather use some compiler-specific library routine. So, to use a Python script, maybe we can use `call system( "sleep.py 7" )` etc? (where `sleep.py` is a Python script as shown in your link.) This seems to work on my mac...

Comment: gfortran does not use /usr/bin/sleep.  For your code, you can use the -fdump-tree-original option to generate intermediate code, which shows that gfortran calls the library routine `_gfortran_sleep_i4_sub`.  On a real Unix-like operating system, this routine calls sleep(3), which is a part of the C standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem was fixed through a combination of solutions suggested by @roygvib in the comments. The main issue is that `sleep` in the WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) environment is broken. The first step is to replace the broken `/usr/bin/sleep` with [this Python script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253473/777167):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

time.sleep(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Then, the Fortran program is modified to make a `system` call to this new `sleep` executable:

```
program sleep
    print*, "Sleeping"
    call system("sleep 30")
    print*, "Done"
end program sleep
```

Until the next update of WSL, this hack will have to do.

Comment: Looks like a problem in nanosleep (use strace on your executable).  On 18.04 it waits and returns 0, on 20.04 it returns invalid argument.

Comment: The difference is that on 18.04 it uses nanosleep but on 20.04, it uses clock_nanosleep.  The clock_nanosleep problem is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747896/usleep-not-working-invalid-argument-error.  If you drop back to Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL, your original program will work.

Answer (score 1):

The `sleep` procedure is not part of the Fortran standard and non-portable. Here is a solution that would potentially work on all systems with any standard-compliant Fortran compiler:

```
module sleep_mod

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: IK => int64, RK => real64, output_unit
    implicit none

contains

    subroutine sleep(seconds)

        implicit none

        real(RK), intent(in) :: seconds ! sleep time
        integer(IK)          :: countOld, countNew, countMax
        real(RK)             :: countRate

        call system_clock( count=countOld, count_rate=countRate, count_max=countMax )
        if (countOld==-huge(0_IK) .or. nint(countRate)==0_IK .or. countMax==0_IK) then
            write(output_unit,"(A)") "Error occurred. There is no processor clock."
            error stop
        end if

        countRate = 1._RK / countRate
        do
            call system_clock( count=countNew )
            if (countNew==countMax) then
                write(output_unit,"(A)") "Error occurred. Maximum processor clock count reached."
                error stop
            end if
            if ( real(countNew-countOld,kind=RK) * countRate > seconds ) exit
            cycle
        end do

    end subroutine sleep

end module sleep_mod

program main
    use sleep_mod, only: output_unit, sleep, RK
    implicit none
    write(output_unit,"(A)") "Sleep for 5 second."
    call execute_command_line(" ") ! flush stdout
    call sleep(seconds = 5._RK)
    write(output_unit,"(A)") "Wake up."
end program main
```

You can test it online here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php